# Yii required checkbox with condition

Tags: php, checkbox, yii

I have an ActiveForm with four checkboxes:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'admin')->checkbox() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'newsletterAccess')->checkbox() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'groupAccess')->checkbox() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'templateAccess')->checkbox() ?>
```

and when the first checkbox is checked (admin), the form can only be submitted when all four checkboxes are checked.
What should my rule look like? I tried something like this:

```
[['newsletterAccess', 'groupAccess', 'templateAccess'], 'compare', 'compareValue' => true, 
            'when' => function ($model) {
                return $model->admin == 1;
            }
```

but it didn't work. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need operator too

```
[['newsletterAccess', 'groupAccess', 'templateAccess'], 'compare', 
      'compareValue' => true,  
      'operator' => '==' 
        'when' => function ($model) {
            return $model->admin == 1;
        }
```